# why monkey patching breaks staticmethods

Tags: python, static-methods, monkeypatching

Below is a simplified version of our production code that gave us an unexpected result after monkey patching. We have 3 classes here inherited in a chain Base -> A -> B. Those classes execute the Action class, which in this example just prints the passed string.

```
class Action():
    """an action prints passed argument when executed"""
    
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    
    def run(self):
        print(self.arg)

#chain of classes Base -> A -> B
class Base():
    name="base"
    
    @classmethod
    def actions(cls):
        return [Action(cls.name)]
        
        
class A(Base):
    name="AAAA"
    

class B(A):
    name="BBBB"


#sanity check
A.actions()[0].run() #AAAA
B.actions()[0].run() #BBBB
```

this prints:

AAAA

BBBB

as expected

we needed to monkey patch the middle class (A) and that operation affected class B. I'm trying to wrap my head around why?

```
#extend the actions of class "A" with an extra one by monkey patching "actions" classmethod

@classmethod
def newActions(cls):
    return cls.old_actions() + [Action("foobar")] #retrieve actions from the old classmethod and extend it

A.old_actions = A.actions #store the old actions classmethod for later use
A.actions = newActions #monkey patch actions

#sanity check
A.actions()[0].run() #AAAA
B.actions()[0].run() #AAAA ???
```

after monkey patching, all actions refer to class A and I would love to understand why it is happening

**solution:**

the problem with the above is how the old_actions are being stored. they need to be rewrapped as a classmethod as well

`A.old_actions = classmethod(A.actions.im_func)`

Answer (score 0):

Like regular methods, classmethods bind on access. When you do

```
A.old_actions = A.actions
```

evaluating `A.actions` gives you a bound method, not a classmethod.

This line sets `A.old_actions` to a bound method with `cls` bound to `A`. Accessing `B.old_actions` will run the method with `cls` still bound to `A` rather than `B`.

---

When you call `B.actions()`, that calls your monkey-patched `newActions` with `cls` set to `B`, but `newActions` will call `cls.old_actions()`, which runs your original `actions` method with `cls` set to `A`, as described above.

Your original `actions` method then finds `"AAAA"` instead of `"BBBB"` when it accesses `cls.name`, because it's running with the wrong `cls`.

Comment: right. so to fix it the only change needed is A.old_actions = classmethod(A.actions.im_func)